# How to use Tensorflow Keras API

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

Well I start learning Tensorflow but I notice there's so much confusion about how to use this thing..
First, some tutorials present models using low level API tf.varibles, scopes...etc, but other tutorials use Keras instead and for example to use tensor board to invoke callbacks.
Second, what's the purpose of having ton of duplicate API, really what's the purpose behind  using high level API like Keras when you have low  level to build  model like Lego blocks?
Finally, what's the true purpose of using eager execution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these APIs all together. E.g. if you have a regular dense network, but with an special layer you can use higher level API for dense layers (tf.layers and tf.keras) and low level API for your special layer.  Furthermore, it is complex graphs are easier to define in low level APIs, e.g. if you want to share variables, etc.

Eager execution helps you for fast debugging, it evaluates tensors directly without a need of invoking a session.

Comment: thank you your reply and before i can mark your reply as valid answer, can you able to provide a simple demonstration with mixed API and Tensorboard/TensorGraph.

Answer (score 0):

There are different "levels" of APIs (high-level APIs such as keras and estimators, and low level APIs such as Variables, etc) to suit different developer needs.

For the average industry developer, who already knows approximately what ML model you intend to use, keras is a good fit. For example, if you know you want to implement a sequential model with two dense layers with softmax activation, you need only do something like:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
  keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Using keras is generally simpler as you don't have to think about low-level implementation details such as tf.Variables. For more complete examples, check out the [keras tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/) on tensorflow.org.

The low-level API allows users finer control over the models you're developing. These APIs are more commonly used by developers and researchers developing novel ML methods; for example, if you need a specialized layer that does something different from canonical ML methods, you can manually define a layer using low level APIs.

Finally, eager execution is an imperative programming style. It enables faster debugging, and has a gentler learning curve for those new to tensorflow, since it is more "pythonic"/intuitive. Check out the [eager guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) for more.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. Let's assume that I make model for segementation using low level API and I have a pretrained VGG16 using Keras API I downloaded from the internet (I checked the *.py file and I found it use Keras API) does things work correctly if or I need a pretrained VGG implemented in low level API?